# Do not return the index.hmtl on root url instead return 403 Access is denied

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service, redirect

When I enter www.mydomain.com the index.html file is returned.

I do not want that.

On the base url I want to return a 403 Access is denied, **how can I do that**?

Only when the base url AND further routes/path are appended I want that the

index.html is loaded, because then the frontend can catch the route values

initially for further backend calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the base url I want to return a 403 Access is denied, how can I do that?

Based on your requirement, you could leverage the following url rewrite rule:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Block the request from the root url and return 403" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^$" />
             <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied."/>
                </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Moreover, you could also remove the `index.html` document under `Application settings > Default documents` of your azure web app as follows:

[image]